# How to display calculator inside dialog box

Tags: android

How  to display `calculator inside dialog box in android`? I saw some examples but they add only view inside dialog box, but I want to add `whole activity inside dialog`.

Comment: You can use FragmentDialog class

Answer (score 0):

You can put the following line inside your AndroidManifest, to make your activity like a dialog.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

Comment: can we do it programmatically ? without changing  androidmanifest

Comment: you can call **setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);** before calling     **setContentView();** in your **onCreate()**